# dynamic_cast to generic array

Tags: .net, generics, visual-c++, c++-cli, dynamic-cast

I'm getting the following error

`error C2680: 'cli::array<Type> ^' : invalid target type for dynamic_cast`

When trying to compile the following code:

```
generic<typename T>
static void Test()
{
    Object^ obj = gcnew Object();
    array<T>^ test = dynamic_cast<array<T>^>(obj);
}
```

It works fine using safe_cast. Is there no way to do this with dynamic_cast, or do I have to use safe_cast and catch the exception when it fails? C# is easily able to do this with the `as` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now convinced that this is a MSVC bug, [which I have reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/899050/msvc-fails-to-compile-c-cli-code-containing-dynamic-cast-to-array-of-generic-type).